# LINQ in Property Getter - Poor Performance?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, design-patterns

Consider the following snippet:

```
    private List<object> MyList;

    public List<object> SubSetOfList
    {
        get { return MyList.Where(p => p.Property == SomeValue).ToList(); }
    }
```

This is an extremely convenient way of accessing the sub-set of the list that I am interested in. However, I imagine it may not scale so well in terms of performance.

Another pattern I considered follows. I don't care for this one though since it has scaling problems in terms of complexity as the number of sub-sets that I am interested in increase.

```
    private List<object> _myList;
    public List<object> WholeList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
    }

    private List<object> _valueAList; 
    public List<object> ValueAList
    {
        get { return _valueAList; }
    }

    private List<object> _valueBList;
    public List<object> ValueBList
    {
        get { return _valueBList; }
    }

    public void AddItem(object obj)
    {
        _myList.Add(obj);

        if (obj.SomePropety == valueA)
            _valueAList.Add(obj);
        if (obj.SomePropety == valueB)
            _valueBList.Add(obj);
    }
```

Is there a generally accepted pattern, or patterns, to handle this kind of behavior?

Comment: "However, I imagine it may not scale so well in terms of performance." - I think you should really profile your application to see if that's really a problem before dropping the readable solution for something complicated.

Comment: It would be useful to know what LINQ provider you are using (e.g. Objects, Entity Framework) and how often you expect to be accessing this property. In general you can mitigate any performance concerns with this approach by caching the result of ToList and returning the cached version on subsequent calls.

Comment: It might be better to not execute the query with `ToList` even with a fixed value in `SubSetOfList`. You should also not use a property for something "expensive". Then use a method with an argument instead.

Comment: Just to be clear, and respond to the repeated mentions of 'don't claim bad performance without profiling,' - I didn't. This was a question about the problem. I was wondering if there was an accepted solution that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entirely depends on your requirements. If you have some sort of storage requirement your second solution would indeed scale badly.
If you have performance requirements than always creating a list may also scale badly.

A possible solution would be to use your first solution but store the resulting list and create it only when accessed, e.g.

```
private List<object> MyList;

private List<object> _subList;
public List<object> SubSetOfList
{
    get { return _subList ?? (_subList = MyList.Where(p => p.Property == SomeValue).ToList();) }
}
```

This is a sort of lazy evaluation as it is done once. You need of course handle consistency by yourself as changing MyList would need to invalidate the stored subList.

Another solution would be to return an `IEnumerable<object>` which is evaluated lazily. But bear in mind that every user of this type would need to re-evaluate it over and over. If your operations contain many `First()`, `Last()` etc than indeed this would be faster as no one has ever evaluated the entire list before, like (@D Stanley has mentioned).

But be aware that people tend to evaluate `IEnumerables` sometimes more than once resulting in a definitive performance loss. e.g calling Any() and then other calls to an `IEnumerable`. Then the caller should properly use a ToList etc to evaluate the list only once.

And also a repetition: No performance claim without profiling

Comment: *You need of course handle consistency by yourself* You could use an `ObservableCollection<T>` for `MyList` instead of a `List<T>` and set `_subList` to `null` in a `CollectionChanged` event handler. So, this is an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, don't *assume* anything is a performance problem until you *measure it* against a reasonable alternative.  That said, some options that *may* improve performance are:

1. Exposing the lists as `IEnumerable`s instead of `List`s to take advantage of deferred execution.  (e.g. operations like `First` would be faster because you wouldn't need to hydrate an entire list)
2. Caching the filtered lists (being sure to clear the cache if a new item is added or a property changed that affects the lists)
3. Using Dictionaries to improve lookup by property (again maintianing the dictionaries whren an item is added or property changed)
4. Maintaining separate lists like you suggest.

You'll have to decide if the performance improvement is worth the extra maintenance.  Personally I would start with a simpler solution and only refactoring if the improvement justifies the risk and work.